# Reverse engineering to MSP432P401R LaunchPad Development Kit

Tags: reverse-engineering, dev-kit

I have this LaunchPad Development Kit(MSP432P401R):
[image]

I connected the kit to the computer using USB (Like in the image), and through the PuTTY software I was able to receive the output and input to the program that was burned in the kit.
Now I want to do a Reverse Engineer for the burned software in the kit and I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Asking how to reverse-engineer something is really too broad a question. But if you just want to learn how the code works surely being a development kit the source code would be available anyway?

Comment: What is to reverse engineer? Everything can be found here http://www.ti.com/product/MSP432P401R/technicaldocuments including the design files. And if you get Code Composer Studio you should be able to get the code to.

Comment: That software is called "out-of-box demo".

Comment: ... and can be found at http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSP-EXP432P401R/latest/index_FDS.html

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the thing is that there is software burning on the kit and there is no source code, I want to do reverse engineering kit and from there I will manage by myself already in Arm Assembly

Comment: In addition the kit have JTAG maybe it can help ?

Answer (score 2):

If this thing is truly a development platform, then most likely the schematics and code are provided outright.  The purpose of a development platform is to show what the product can do, and allow for poking around to understand it.

I'm not familiar with the MSP430 ecosystem, but I'd be very surprised if the design isn't available somehow from TI.  Look around on their web site.  If that fails, ask their tech support, local field application engineer, or whatever mechanisms TI provides for customer support.